# Call a aspx page from jsp

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp

In one scenario I want to call one third party aspx page to send some data (or say acknowledgement) from my jsp page.Can any body please help me how I will done this call and does I need to tell some setting to the third party vendor to set from there side ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSTL `c:import` tag. E.g.

```
<c:import url="http://abc.com/info.aspx">
   <c:param name="user">sasha</c:param>
</c:import>
```

This tag results in GET request to the external resource. So, the 3rd party aspx provider must expect a GET request.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.does I need to add some code in the asp.net site or page to accept my request?When I try to open page link in browser it is working fine but when I call it from code its not working(even its working fine in IE some time but not in other browsers)

Comment: You need only assure that your asp page accepts GET requests. What do you mean by "when I call it from code"?

Comment: Try to access your asp by http://your.com/page.aspx?param=value .If it does not work then aspx does not accepts GET requests. If your are able to correct it to do so then do it. If you do not have access to that apsx then here is the solution [How can I post parameters for JSTL import tag (<c:import>)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982814/how-can-i-post-parameters-for-jstl-import-tag-cimport)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax request, if you want to do it in client side, or URL.createConnection()/Apache Http Client if you want to do it on server side.
I tried write some code, but here is better example [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)