# Using <c:import> with method post doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a file form.jsp with a form, that submit to test.jsp.

form.jsp

```
 <form id="formTest" action="test" method="post">
     <input type="text" />
     <input type="submit" value="send"/>
 </form>
```

test.jsp

```
    <p>  this is a test</p>
     <c:import url="/anotherpage" />
```

I'm using SpringMvc. Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/form", method=RequestMethod.GET )
   public String form(){... }

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST )
   public String test(){ ... }

@RequestMapping(value="/anotherpage", method = RequestMethod.GET )
   public String anotherpage(){ ... }
```

When submit button is clicked, the tag `<c:import url="/anotherpage" />` does not work. However 
if i change the method to get :`@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET )`

and

```
 <form id="formTest" action="form" method="get">
```

it works correctly.

Why `<c:import url="/anotherpage" />` only work with method GET?

**Edit:**

I'm using:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982814/how-can-i-post-parameters-for-jstl-import-tag-cimport

Comment: @Gautam , My problem is different. The tag <c:import> does not work when i request test.jsp with POST method. only when i change to GET method.

Comment: <c:import> is not dependent on GET or POST. There is something else you are missing. Please explain what you mean by 'not working'? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Javakid, there's nothing missing. When i change to "GET", the page "/anotherpage" appears inside test.jsp. When i use "POST",the page "/anotherpage" does not appears inside test.jsp. I don't get any exception. But other tags like '<c:forEach>' still works.

Comment: I see. Please can you post the exception that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/anotherpage", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} )
public String anotherpage(){ ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

For some reason jstl doesn't like the  self closing tag.  Try it like this...

```
<c:import url="/anotherpage"></c:import>
```